# Svn Externals, can you have files from externals that are mixed in with your regular working copy

Tags: svn, version-control, external, svn-externals

I want to be able to have a working copy of a framework, then I want to have another repo for certain extensions where I pull those extensions into my framework with externals. The problem I see, since I haven't used externals before, is that it appears you have to just pull in full directories that can be separated out from the rest of the project for example

```
root
  dir
  dir
  extensions
    plugin - external pulled in here
```

But what if you need something where the external directory structure includes some of the normal framework structure, for example:

```
root
   app - This is in working copy and external
     code - This is in working copy and external
        dir - This is only in working copy
        dir - This is only in external
     etc - this is in working copy and external
      file - this is only in working copy
      file - this is from external
```

I hope this makes sense, but basically I want to have my working copy and then pull in files from another repo that have files and folders in the same directories as my working copy already has files and folders.

Answer (score 1):

The `svn:externals` property can also point to files, not just folders.
See the [docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html) about that.